# How do I use the Google Calendar API?

Tags: flutter, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to build my first app with Flutter. I've been doing courses on programming for months now and I'm just ready to experiment making my first app myself. I've taken the Android Basics nanodegree on Udacity, and an extensive Flutter course on Udemy. But like actually applying everything I've learned has become pretty difficult.

I'm lost but I'm just going with the flow trying to learn from my mistakes. So like ultimately I want an app that can automatically import a bunch of Google Calendar events to your personal Google Calendar, and update them if needed. I started with trying to get the user to sign in with Google, so I used a lot of the example code for getting a seamless Google sign on experience. I imported everything below.

----In the pubspec

```
dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter
firebase_core: 0.3.1+1
firebase_analytics: ^1.0.4
google_sign_in: any
flutter_auth_buttons: any
http: ^0.12.0
googleapis: any
```

----In the app.dart file where I'm trying to hold the state of the login

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert' show json;
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_auth_buttons/flutter_auth_buttons.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';
import 'screens/home.dart';
```

So like I don't know if I need the googleapis or if I'm going to be doing this via json and http. And I was confused with service accounts because I thought if I got the permission from the user, it would be doing these changes on behalf of the user.

I simply don't know where to begin with this feature I'm implementing. Like I do have the user logged in, and I got the correct scope as seen below.

----scopes

```
GoogleSignIn googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn(
scopes: <String>[
'email',
'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
],
);
```

Although I will say I don't know what email is doing there and I just borrowed that from the example, when I tried changing it to calendar it just crashed the app. But like what do I take from signing in, like some secret file?

And I was kinda thinking about keeping the user signed into Google because I was going to sync user data to Firebase but I'm not sure if that would be expensive because I've seen red flags with anything to do with Firebase because apparently if you don't implement it correctly, it can cost you an insane amount of money. It's weird to me because it seems you need to utilize Firebase to enable APIs and signing into Google so you can't completely avoid it and I would like to use Firebase but I want to make sure I use it correctly so it doesn't cost an arm and a leg.

If anyone can point me into the correct direction, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Any luck? I am having the same problem and the documentation is very limited especially with flutter.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any lights?